Swan drowns/almost drowns in a water wheel -old Animated movie -
My memory is so foggy on this but i remember watching it at a very young age. I feel like this scene is early on in the film but i'm not 100% sure on that.
What i do remember is a small cottage with a stream near it and a water wheel. a swan is floating gently in the stream then gets sucked into the wheel and struggles a lot. It then either dies and is removed from the water or almost dies and is removed from the water. (I want to say it was removed by a very troll-ish looking creature but i was so young and cannot be certain so don't let that rule anything out)
this was animated and i don't think the swan had much to do with the plot.
given the harshness of it, this is all my memory can recall. I believe it was a very old style animation with a great amount of detail in scenery.

Approximate year of release? Country\language? Pretty sure I know what you're after, but these might help.
